# Error in EJS file with if statement in script tage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am getting this error in ejs when I am putting if statement in script tag

Error

```
summary:118 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: "" is not a function
```

and my code is

```
 let chartArray=[];
 chartArray.push(['Province', 'Cases']);
 `<%for (let p in provinces){%>`
        `<% if(p==province){ %>`
              chartArray.push([`<%=p%>`,dataarray]);
        `<% } %>`
 `<%}%>`
 let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartArray);
```

Its works without if statement but I want the conditions

Comment: Hi Sameed. I assume "province" in `if (p == province)` should be a string? if so, try putting single or double quotes around it to make it string, not a variable. Ex. `if (p == 'province')`

Comment: oh no it an object passed from route